# How would GDPR apply if my app doesn't store anything from users?

Tags: firebase, policy

So I have an app idea. The won't require login or any information from any user (yes, it's a simple thing). How would GDPR apply in this case? The goal is to have AdMob to monetize it.

Another related question, there will be a chatroom, where users are unidentifiable and uncensored (age would be 18+ because of that). Would I be required to keep logs of the entire chatroom?

Comment: If you don't have any information( IP Details, User Email etc.) that can identify a user uniquely, then you can store any content.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it requires legal expertise to answer, not software expertise. It might be on-topic as a question on [Law Stack Exchange](https://law.stackexchange.com/).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your app will be storing things from users!  When you generate that anonymous identifier, you'll be storing it locally then repeatedly using it to identify them. You'll also be dealing with data that the user generates when they type in chat messages. Finally, by bringing in an ads library like AdMob you'll be taking advantage by the advertising IDs provided on both Android and iOS.

Personal information doesn't just mean records like name or phone number, so its worth doing a full audit of the types of data you're storing, and reviewing it with your own legal experts.

Comment: I wouldn't even need to use the anonymous login auth (I don't need any auth method). Would that change anything? No social media integration as well.

Comment: Probably wouldn't change it. You'd still be storing some kind of identifier that would be tied uniquely to that person's device.

Answer (score -1):

Regiin, Frank, as per your comment, it seems like the "first party" cookie case, and in your app case if that data is not used for any targeting or automated decision making it should be fine. Inference drawn from this article from IAPP can be of help: [The ePrivacy Regulation: It’s not just about cookies anymore](https://iapp.org/news/a/its-not-just-about-cookies-anymore/).